# SetNetworkRequirement not respected on WP7.5?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, networking

I am experimenting with sockets and WP7.5. Currently, I am looking into the SetNetworkRequirement property of a socket. I am following this [how-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487165%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), however, the OS seems to ignore the network requirement.

When I set the requirement to cellular, nothing happens when I do ConnectAsync, even when I am only connected to 3G. However, if I am connected to Wifi and use NonCellular, I can see in my tcpdump that a connection is made.

What is strange is that the SDK behavior is not as documented. When I set the requirement to cellular, I still get SocketError.Success, even though I can see that not connection is made. I am also able to send data using this socket, and SendAsync also receives SocketError.Success.

My question is, has anyone seen similar behavior or had any luck setting the network requirement to cellular? Another strange observation is that if I ask the phone to connect to a non-existent IP/port, I see a connection attempt on both interfaces. Based on this, I suspect there is some undocumentet caching going on.

Edit: I did some more debugging on this. The described behavior seems to be linked to be port. If I use any other port than 80, the phone connects with both Cellular and NonCellular.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone experiences the same behavior, everything points to this being an OS bug. There seems to be a  problem related to servers running on port 80, as setNetworkRequirement is respected for every other port (that I have tried).